# SQL Collation conflict when comparing to a column in a temp table

Tags: sql, collation

I have a SQL query that compares a value in the database to a constant:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
INNER JOIN #TempTable tem
    ON my_table.id = temp.id
    AND my_table.key = 'SOME STRING'
```

And I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

How can I get around this? (without making changes to the database)

UPDATE: I get this error even if I remove the last like (the string comparison)...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems your `id`'s are `VARCHAR`s with different collations.

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    my_table
INNER JOIN
        #TempTable tem
ON      my_table.id = temp.id COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        AND my_table.key = 'SOME STRING'
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt noticed that my id's were characters.

Comment: Awesome helped me in a pinch. Surprisingly I got this between two temp tables but either way this worked to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you help with *why* the comparison of different collations isn't allowed?  Is it simply because SQL server doesn't know which collation it should do? I'd like to think it could just use the stricter one...

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: which one is "the stricter one" and how would you define it?

Comment: It might be a bigger discussion with the architects of the DBMS, but I suppose you'd have to have a bunch of automatic-coercion rules.  One that makes sense is that case-sensitive is stricter than case-insensitive.  But I don't pretend to have thought this through fully.  Anyway, I'm just curious if there is anyone that has written on it.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: I'm not entirely sure how you would define "strictness", whatever it is, for a collation. Collation is a set of rules defining how strings compare. I.e. is this condition true: `N'Szalapski' > N'Sалапский'`? (Polish says no, Hungarian says yes). You cannot automatically coerse different collations and leave everyone happy. You can add these two strings, or assign a Polish string to a Hungarian variable and get a meaningful-ish result, but when you compare them, collation kinda matters (>)

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: (>), that's why comparison, MIN, MAX, GREATER and things like that do require that you explicitly bring both sides to a single collation. This is called [collation sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#collation-sensitive-and-collation-insensitive)

Answer (score 5):

Specify the collation inside the declaration of your temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ID NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE database_default)
```

Comment: +1 But OP misdiagnosed the problem. The problem column was id, not key.  I've adjusted your answer to reflect as such.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the temp table. It uses the collation of the tempdb.

You could create a table in your actual db and not a temp table and then they would have the same collation. Or specify collation upon creating temp table.

Comment: Not true - depending on how the temp table was created, it would either take the collation of the database you are in, or the collation of tempdb - not master.
If the temp table is explicitly created (CREATE TABLE #temp) then it takes the collation from tempdb.
If the table is derived from another table (SELECT * INTO #temp from mytable) then it takes the collation from the source table.

Comment: Good point ... as they are created at the same time I *wrongly* usually look at collation of master to find collation of tempdb. editted to incorporate correct answer. Ta :)

Comment: Bad advice to workaround by creating a 'normal-temporary' table in your actual db. There are two techniques to ensure the temp table uses a compatible collation: Kev Riley gives one, (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1404916/224704) has the other.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
INNER JOIN #TempTable temp    
    ON my_table.id = temp.id collate database_default
    AND my_table.key = 'SOME STRING'
```