# different collation on different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a table (table1) with collation **Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**. I have written a procedure which will create insert script for the newly inserted data in the table (table1). I am using this script to insert data in the other table (table2) with same structure but different collation **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**. Till now its working fine. I want to know will it create any problem in the future. If yes then, in what scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[Collation affects only how data are sorted and compared](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3302341/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm). So it cannot cause any problem with inserts. But it can cause [problems when comparing the column values of the two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404880/sql-collation-conflict-when-comparing-to-a-column-in-a-temp-table). For multi-language data consider using `nvarchar` vs `varchar`.